# Rails caching: Action caching or HTTP caching or Both? How to invalidate cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, heroku, memcached

I'm using rails 4.2.7 and by default, there is no action caching or page caching, and it'll be running on Heroku which doesn't support page caching.  So, I'm using https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching gem for action caching.

My question is how should I invalidate action caching? I'm using Memcached (memcachier) as cache store
 1. Should I use cache_sweepers(observers), which I think is not supported on rails 5 to clear cache
 2. Clear cache from controller action by using the expire_action method, but the content is added via rails_admin and a different controller which only contains the index and show actions serves the content to visitors. So, I have clear action from rails_admin or from the model if it's possible.
 3. **Auto-expiring cache key like fragment cache** Create unique key based on the various model object which will be shown on the page and their cache_key, this way key will auto expire when the object is changed, similar to how fragment cache works. I tend to use this approach by passing a hash as `cache_path`

I'm also using HTTP cache using `fresh_when` and CloudFlare as CDN, should I use proxy_cache using Memcached or I should not since I'm using CloudFlare and it'll be the repetition of the same. Do you recommend to only use this HTTP cache or use it with action_caching or only use action_caching?